# /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root does not exist, tried all the usual fixes

Tags: boot, encryption, lvm, luks

Sorry about the screenshot but it captures my problem.

[image: Boot screenshot]

Ubuntu 19.10 encrypted LVM2 setup

I have followed all the guides I could find.

Checked rootdelay, /proc/modules exists, did cryptsetup luksOpen etc. as described here - [Update initramfs](https://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/recovering-from-unbootable-ubuntu-encrypted-lvm-root-partition/) Removed all my nvidia drivers. Removed a broken lvm raid0 setup on drives specifically used to store data.

The result is no difference, still cannot boot.

lsblk output

```
NAME                    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
loop0                     7:0    0   1.9G  1 loop  
loop1                     7:1    0  89.1M  1 loop  
loop2                     7:2    0  54.5M  1 loop  
loop3                     7:3    0 149.9M  1 loop  
loop4                     7:4    0   4.2M  1 loop  
loop5                     7:5    0  14.8M  1 loop  
loop6                     7:6    0   956K  1 loop  
loop7                     7:7    0  44.2M  1 loop  
sda                       8:0    0  55.9G  0 disk  
sdb                       8:16   0  55.9G  0 disk  
sdc                       8:32   0 223.6G  0 disk  
├─sdc1                    8:33   0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sdc2                    8:34   0   732M  0 part  /boot
└─sdc3                    8:35   0 222.4G  0 part  
  └─sdc3_crypt          253:0    0 222.3G  0 crypt 
    ├─ubuntu--vg-root   253:1    0 221.4G  0 lvm   /
    └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 253:2    0   976M  0 lvm   
sdd                       8:48   0   1.8T  0 disk  
├─sdd1                    8:49   0 245.9G  0 part  
└─sdd2                    8:50   0 808.4G  0 part  
sde                       8:64   0  59.6G  0 disk  
sdf                       8:80   1   7.5G  0 disk  
├─sdf1                    8:81   1   2.3G  0 part  
├─sdf2                    8:82   1   3.9M  0 part  
└─sdf3                    8:83   1   5.2G  0 part  
sr0                      11:0    1  1024M  0 rom   
nvme0n1                 259:0    0 238.5G  0 disk  
└─nvme0n1p1             259:1    0 238.5G  0 part
```

Relevant part of fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/mapper/sdc3_crypt: 222.3 GiB, 238734540800 bytes, 466278400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 221.4 GiB, 237674430464 bytes, 464207872 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 976 MiB, 1023410176 bytes, 1998848 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

My pastebin of boot-repair, which failed, http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/4WvZMF9ryt

```
root@ubuntu:/# lvdisplay /dev/ubuntu-vg
WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
--- Logical volume ---
LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-vg/root
LV Name                root
VG Name                ubuntu-vg
LV UUID                IG4WUN-mo8H-a00I-mSIp-CRXW-GscM-FtRJtI
LV Write Access        read/write
LV Creation host, time ubuntu, 2019-06-16 12:14:27 +0100
LV Status              available
# open                 1
LV Size                221.35 GiB
Current LE             56666
Segments               1
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     auto
- currently set to     256
Block device           253:1

--- Logical volume ---
LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-vg/swap_1
LV Name                swap_1
VG Name                ubuntu-vg
LV UUID                wMySoO-ylhz-0s9d-W5o9-lkc2-4O5B-hKwXB2
LV Write Access        read/write
LV Creation host, time ubuntu, 2019-06-16 12:14:28 +0100
LV Status              available
# open                 0
LV Size                976.00 MiB
Current LE             244
Segments               1
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     auto
- currently set to     256
Block device           253:2
```

Content of /etc/crypttab

```
sdc3_crypt UUID=11bc3fcd-1ac1-4b4c-a49d-56986510d151 none luks,discard
```

Content of /etc/fstab

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sdc2 during installation
UUID=d62c1e94-2455-4b9d-80ff-eb6197d718d5 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2

# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdc1 during installation
UUID=485D-94E1  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=7bb37d0e-00df-4580-be16-623fc5b0a86b   /media/home    ext4          defaults       0       2
/dev/disk/by-uuid/52f75980-12b1-44b7-b6d5-bd70ea3bd4cd /mnt/52f75980-12b1-44b7-b6d5-bd70ea3bd4cd auto nosuid,nodev$
/dev/disk/by-uuid/7538bb0e-c514-4b1e-a451-5a6b3fad49f4 /mnt/7538bb0e-c514-4b1e-a451-5a6b3fad49f4 auto nosuid,nodev$
/dev/disk/by-uuid/eb58ba0d-8dd6-418e-b8d3-8b7757f2d17e /mnt/eb58ba0d-8dd6-418e-b8d3-8b7757f2d17e auto nosuid,nodev$
/dev/disk/by-uuid/fecc8e85-2668-4593-be7d-314b4964e964 
/mnt/fecc8e85-2668-4593-be7d-314b4964e964 auto nosuid,nodev$
```

What next to solve this issue?

UPDATE 1:

I tried the steps of the "Update initramfs" article linked to above again, after changing the crypttab file to this

```
sdc3_crypt /dev/sdc3 none luks,discard
```

Also changing the CRYPTSETUP=y in /etc/cryptsetup-initramfs/conf-hook

Then got this on the last step 'update-initramfs -c -k all'

```
cryptsetup: ERROR: Couldn't fnd sysfs directory for 253:1
```

Google search returned 7 posts, none of which explained the cause of the error. But removed the CRYPTSETUP=y and retried. This completed the process, but same error on reboot

Comment: At this point having wasted 2 whole days trying things that google throws up on my error messages I think that unless someone has a better suggestion I will have to re install. Which linux ditro has the most support when things go wrong?

Comment: Tried this https://blog.wohli.org/2016/10/05/Installing-Ubuntu-16-10-on-existing-LUKS-encrypted-LVM/ and ended up with this error - "cryptsetup: Waiting for encrypted source device UUID=blah"